# Proper way to modify public interface

Tags: class, oop, interface

Let's assume we have a function that returns a list of apples in our warehouse:

```
List<Apple> getApples();
```

After some lifetime of the application we've found a bug - in rare cases clients of this function get intoxication because some of the apples returned are not ripe yet.

However another set of clients absolutely does not care about ripeness, they use this function simply to know about all available apples.

Naive way of solving this problem would be to add the 'ripeness' member to an apple and then find all places where ripeness can cause problems and put some checks.

```
const auto apples = getApples();
for (const auto& apple : apples)
    if (apple.isRipe())
        consume(apple)
```

However, if we correlate this new requirement of having ripe apples with the way class interfaces are usually designed, we might find out that we need new interface which is a subset of a more generic one:

```
List<Apple> getRipeApples();
```

which basically extends the getApples() interface by filtering the ones that are not ripe.

So the questions are:

1. Is this correct way of thinking?
2. Should the old interface (getApples) remain unchanged?
3. How will it handle scaling if later on we figure out that some customers are allergic to red/green/yellow apples (getRipeNonRedApples)?
4. Are there any other alternative ways of modifying the API?

One constraint, though: how do we minimize the probability of inexperienced/inattentive developer calling getApples instead of getRipeApples? Subclass the Apple with the RipeApple? Make a downcast in the getRipeApples?

Answer (score 1):

A [pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/the-capability-pattern-future-) found often with Java people is the idea of versioned capabilities.

You have something like:

```
interface Capability ...

interface AppleDealer {
  List<Apples> getApples();
}
```

and in order to retrieve an AppleDealer, there is some central service like

```
public <T> T getCapability (Class<T> type);
```

So your client code would be doing:

```
AppleDealer dealer = service.getCapability(AppleDealer.class);
```

When the need for another method comes up, you go:

```
interface AppleDealerV2 extends AppleDealer { ...
```

And clients that want V2, just do a `getCapability(AppleDealerV2.class) call. Those that don't care don't have to modify their code!

**Please note**: of course, this only works for **extending** interfaces. You can't use this approach neither to *change* signatures nor to *remove* methods in existing interfaces.

Regarding your question 3/4: I go with MaxZoom there, but to be precise: I would very much recommend for "flags" to be something like `List<String>`, or `List<Integer>` (for 'real' int like flags) or even `Map<String, Object>`. In other words: if you really don't know what kind of conditions might come over time, go for interfaces that work for everything: like one where you can give a map with "keys" and "expected values" for the different keys. If you go for pure enums there, you quickly run into similar "versioning" issues.

Alternatively: consider to allow your client to do the filtering himself, using something [like](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/006-how-to-filter-arraylist-stream-java8/); using Java8 you can think of Predicates, lambdas and all that stuff.

Example:

```
Predicate<Apple> applePredicate = new Predicate<Apple>() {
  @Override
  public boolean test(Apple a) {
    return a.getColour() == AppleColor.GoldenPoisonFrogGolden;
  }
};

List<Apples> myApples = dealer.getApples(applePredicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO creating new class/method for any possible Apple combination will result in a code pollution. The situation described in your post could be gracefully handled by introducing flags parameter :

```
List<Apple> getApples();      // keep for backward compatibility
List<Apple> getApples(FLAGS); // use flag as a filter
```

Possible flags:

- RED_FLAG
- GREEN_FLAG
- RIPE_FLAG
- SWEET_FLAG

So a call like below could be possible:

```
List<Apple> getApples(RIPE_FLAG & RED_FLAG & SWEET_FLAG);
```

that will produce a list of apples that are ripe, and red-delicious.

Comment: One (more advanced) variation to the above solution would be to have criteria object instead of flags. The criteria object would contain all filters that needs to be applied for desired solution.